# Is it possible to hide a partially displayed list item in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of attributes (`ul`) in a box next to another box. I need both boxes to be the same height and so I need to ensure that all the contents of the attribute list are held in the box.

A screenshot to explain:

This is the bottom of my list:

[image: First list attempt]

So then I tried overflow but then you end up with a partial list item being displayed, when I'd rather it just not show up.

Comment: You want partially-shown list items to not appear and leave a void instead ?

Comment: @DanielBatkilin Yes, it would be best case scenario.

Comment: I say take the easy approach and limit the amount of visible <LI> elements .. First you calculate the height of the container ( say it's 200 ), then lets say the list item is 10 pixels high > and list item after the 20th needs to be hidden >>> ul.something li:nth-of-type(10) ~ li

Answer (score 3):

Use the brute, simple approach.
Calculate how many list items can go in the parent container :

1.) Lets say ul is 40 pixels high

2.) Lets say li is 20 pixels high

```
ul li:nth-of-type(2) ~ li {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NBurh/1/

If you want scrolling and fancy tricks you will have to use javascript to calculate the max visible elements ( instead of parent height add together the height of the parent + the amount scrolled to know which elements are visible )

Please note I used visibility:hidden instead of display:none.

I do that so that the scrollbar can encompass the hidden elements if you want to implement show-hide during scrolling with javascript.

If you do not plan on that -> replace visibility:hidden with display:none which removes the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is your list:

```css
#derp {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#derp>li {
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id="derp">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, only two items actually fit, the third is sliced and the fourth is right out. Now let's apply some magic...

```css
#derp {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  
  column-width: 150px;
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#derp>li {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

  break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul id="derp">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And that's it! By enabling columns, the browser will start making columns as soon as the item can't fit, and by using `break-inside: avoid` the individual items will not be split, they'll just move to the next column. Finally, `overflow: hidden` ensures that this new column is out of sight.

Comment: I can see the third item cut in the middle on latest chrome.. Do you have a bug in that code? Kind of curious to see how this works.

Comment: Ah. Chrome *still* doesn't support Columns natively. Add `-webkit-column-width:150px` and `-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid` in the appropriate locations and it should work fine.

Comment: edit the answer to add that in case someone looks for it

Comment: @DanielBatkilin Done, although apparently Firefox doesn't support them either - in fact it doesn't even have any kind of `break-inside: avoid` substitute from what I can tell... And people say IE sucks...

Comment: It's been long since microsoft was the reason for inconsistencies in implementations .. lately chrome has been much worse with firefox not far behind. Opera is underrated

Comment: @DanielBatkilin Tell me about it. Recently Firefox has been crashing on my website because of a `transform: scale` with `transition` to go from 0 to 1...